# Populate Multiple Textboxes Using Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a textbox that is popluated using the jquery autocomplete feature. The source of my autocomplete results are gathered via a ASP.NET web service from an XML file. The XML file has a basic structure like this:

```
<RAIL_INTERSECTIONS>
   <RAIL_INT RR="BNSF" RR_DIV="FED" RR_SUBDIV="MAIN" ADDRESS="6700" STREET="LINCOLN" BRANCH="ALVIN" MILE_POST="146" />
   ...
</RAIL_INTERSECTIONS>
```

The auto-complete pulls the STREET attributes from the file and populates my textbox.

In addition, there are two other textboxes on my form that I would like to auto-populate based on the selection of the value in the auto-complete textbox. Those values are also contained in the XML file--RR and RR_DIV as shown above. Right now, I simply use the following code to call my webservice and get a single value for the street.

```
$(function () {
    $(".tb").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "rail_intersection_info.asmx/GetCrossingLocations",
                data: "{ 'location': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

My abbreviated web service looks something like this:

```
List<string> streets = new List<string>();

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(XmlCrossingFile));

XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("RAIL_INT");
for (int i = 0; i < xmlNodeList.Count; i++ )
{
    streets.Add(xmlNodeList[i].Attributes["STREET"].Value);
}

var data = streets.Where(m => m.ToLower().StartsWith(location.ToLower()));

return data.ToList();
```

My question is, how can I return multiple values from my web service and auto-popluate the other textboxes based on the selected value of the first textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you fire off another AJAX query when the item is selected and populates the text field with the results? Send the selected item value and have the server reply with the data you want to populate.

In the AJAX success method, set the textboxes to what ever the data has:

```
$('input[name=textbox1]').change(function(){
    $.ajax(
    {
        ...
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('input[name=otherTextbox1]').val(data.el1);
            $('input[name=otherTextbox2]').val(data.el2);
        }
    ...
```